# Mat-Nav-List horizontal instead of vertical?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How do I make the following horizontal instead of the (apparent default) of vertical?  It is located within navigation.component.html within my Angular 5.2.7 application that was generated via Angular-CLI 1.7.2.  The documentation link included in the comment does not discuss how to layout a Material navigation bar horizontally.

```html
<mat-nav-list>
  <!--https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview-->
  <mat-list-item>
    <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item>
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
  </mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item>
    <a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact Us</a>
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Answer (score 15):

I was able to create a horizontal `mat-nav-list` by using some custom scss.  I attach it using the class `list-horizontal`.

```
<mat-nav-list class="list-horizontal">
  ...
</mat-nav-list>
```

Here's the scss I used for `list-horizontal`:

```
mat-nav-list.list-horizontal {
  padding: 0;
  .mat-list-item {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

[Here's a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-horizontal-nav-list) to show it working with Angular Material 7.

Answer (score 8):

Setting the container's **display** to `flex` and the **flex-direction** to `row` did the trick for me.

```
<mat-nav-list class="list-horizontal">
     <a mat-list-item href="#">Home</a>
     <a mat-list-item href="#">About</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

And the SCSS file:

```
mat-nav-list.list-horizontal {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Works very well. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I used FlexBox setting fxLayout="row" (or just put in fxLayout as default is row)

```
<mat-nav-list fxLayout="row">
     <a mat-list-item href="#">One</a>
     <a mat-list-item href="#">Two</a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

However, this is using Angular Flex-Layout so an extra package

Answer (score 4):

you have to float each list item

**in css file put:**

```
.mat-list-item {
  float: right;
}
```

**in html file put your code:**

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <!--https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview-->
    <mat-list-item>
        <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
    </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item>
        <a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact Us</a>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block;` would be a better choice, surely?

Comment: float:right provides a horizontal layout but at the expense of left-justification within that horizontal layout.  I want a horizontal, left-justified navigation bar.

display: inline-block fails to provide the desired horizontal layout.

Still looking for an answer as of August 15, 2018.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using mat-tab-nav-bar, since nothing else in Angular Material seems to support horizontal, left-justified, Angular 6-compatible navigation bars, at least as of mid-August 2018.

A full Angular 6.x example can be found in the [Angular Material Horizontal Navigation Bar Example](https://github.com/fmorriso/angular-material-nav) I put together using Angular-CLI 6.x, Angular 6.x and Angular Material 6.x.

Answer (score 0):

Set ***mat-nav-list*** to flex container then adjust ***mat-list-item*** height and padding

I am using angular/flex-layout but you can achieve the same with css/scss

```
<mat-nav-list fxLayout>
<mat-list-item fxFlex>
    <a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a>
</mat-list-item>
<mat-list-item fxFlex>
    <a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a>
</mat-list-item>
<mat-list-item fxFlex>
    <a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact Us</a>
</mat-list-item> </mat-nav-list>
```

Comment: Even `<mat-nav-list fxLayout>` alone is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Add `style="display: flex"` or if using bootstrap `class="d-flex"` to the `<mat-action-list>` element. Not tried on `<mat-nav-list>`. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This css rule worked for me:

```
mat-nav-list.list-horizontal {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   mat-list-item {
        width: min-content;
   }
}
```

applying it in the corresponding html file as follows:

```
<mat-nav-list class="list-horizontal">
 ....
</mat-nav-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I did to handle that horizontal navbar issue:

```
<mat-nav-list class="lists_class">
 <a routerLink="link" mat-list-item matLine class="link_class">name</a>
<mat-nav-list>

.lists_class {
    width: 100%;
}
.link_class {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: min-content;
}
```

The key for me was adjusting the width. Hope this works/helps, cheers!