# How to display mat-list-items left to right

Tags: angular, angular-material

When using Angular Material `mat-nav-list` I want the `login` and `logout` list items next to each other from left to right. What should I do?

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <mat-icon class="example-icon">favorite</mat-icon>
        <mat-icon class="example-icon">delete</mat-icon>
        <span>User name</span>
        <span class="example-spacer"></span>
            <mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item routerLink="login" >Login</a>
                <a mat-list-item routerLink="login" >Logout</a>
            </mat-nav-list>    
    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mat-Nav-List horizontal instead of vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161039/mat-nav-list-horizontal-instead-of-vertical)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to not use `mat-nav-list` and restructure your HTML as follows and use `mat-button` for your `login` and `logout` links:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-icon class="example-icon">favorite</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="example-icon">delete</mat-icon>
    <span>User name</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <a mat-button routerLink="login">Login</a>
    <a mat-button routerLink="login">Logout</a>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

The `mat-button` directive seems to suit what you want better because they will display inline by default. Note the explanation in the [Angular Material Docs on mat-button](https://v8.material.angular.io/components/button/overview) which explains where you should use `<button>` as opposed to `<a>`. If you don't intend to navigate away from the page, you should use `<button>` elements instead.

Adding extra CSS as suggested in [Mat-Nav-List horizontal instead of vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161039/mat-nav-list-horizontal-instead-of-vertical) is fine, but if you want to avoid custom CSS and use Angular Material itself, use `mat-button`.

Comment: Thank You, I followed Your post. Mat-button is ok.

Comment: Cool, I remember trying to do something similar inside a mat-toolbar and ended up with messy CSS for layout when all I needed was the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some CSS in order to do it. You can read about Flex CSS here: [CSS Flexible Box Layout - Basic Concepts](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-toolbar-row>
      <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
  <mat-toolbar-row>
    <mat-icon class="example-icon">favorite</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon class="example-icon">delete</mat-icon>
    <span>User name</span>
    <span class="example-spacer"></span>
    <mat-nav-list class="my-nav-list">
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="login" >Login</a>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="login" >Logout</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

```css
.my-nav-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use angular flex to achieve this layout like as you are also using Angular material so try this

```
    <div class="iq-actn" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" fxLayoutAlign="flex-start center">
     <a fxFlex matRipple>Log In</a>
     <a fxFlex matRipple>Log Out</a>
   </div>
```